# Android Key Hash

Tags: android

I wanna to create hash key for Single Sign On Appliction in FaceBook.. If i enter this Commands in Command prompt

C:\Users\FSSD6>keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/d
ebug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

i am getting error ::

'openssl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
 what can i do for it..

I am having my openssl bin file in location (C:\Users\FSSD6\Desktop\openssl-0.9.8k_WIN32\bin) and i am having my keystore in  ( C:\Users\FSSD6.android\debug.keystore)

Please help me..thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the openssl bin directory is in your path or, alternatively, specify the full path when trying to run it.

Comment: i also face this problem..but i dint get opesssl,i search for this but did'nt get. github is installed on my pc, i get its openssl file ,is it useful?

Answer (score 3):

openssl is not in your path. Try:

```
C:\Users\FSSD6>keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/d ebug.keystore | C:\Users\FSSD6\Desktop\openssl-0.9.8k_WIN32\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | C:\Users\FSSD6\Desktop\openssl-0.9.8k_WIN32\bin\openssl base64
```

Or add `C:\Users\FSSD6\Desktop\openssl-0.9.8k_WIN32\bin` to your PATH.

Answer (score 2):

I have got the solution for getting hash key on android.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>cd .android

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\.android>keytool -exportcert -alias andr
oiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | "C:\Documents and Settings\Adm
inistrator\.android\openssl\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary | "C:\Documents and Settin
gs\Administrator\.android\openssl\bin\openssl" base64
3ZLW/TAqPavR43aZh79aejFQDOdka8=

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\.android>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yours;

> C:\Users\FSSD6>keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore
>   ~/.android/d ebug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

Must be;

> C:\Users\FSSD6>keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore
>   ~/.android/debug.keystore | C:\Users\FSSD6\Desktop\openssl-0.9.8k_WIN32\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64